# How to run DockerOperator when Airflow is already a docker container?

Tags: airflow

I currently have an Airflow instance running with `docker-compose`. In the future, I will be moving to a kubernetes cluster. So, Airflow will always be running in a docker container.

That being said, how do I run a `DockerOperator` when Airflow itself is inside a docker container?

It's a docker-in-docker inception problem that I don't fully understand how to mitigate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could map docker socket inside the container (/var/run/docker.sock)  configure docker engine URL to connect to external Docker engine (Docker architecture is done in the way that you actually run `client` locally and the engine running your docker container runs elsewhere.

Just look for Docker-in-Docker term.

There is currently (as of 2.0.0 Docker Provider) a bug preventing doing that, but it is being addressed in https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/16932 and it will be out in < week - or you can downgrade to previous version of the provider.